# Range and for loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

My question is how exactly does this work? The outcome is 6 16 30. The way I am solving it in my head is to get the first two ranges is 0 so 0 + 0 is 0 as a result and not 6. What am I doing wrong in my head for this example?

````
result = 0
for a in range(5):
    for b in range(4):
        result += a + b
    print(result)
    if result > stop:
        break```
````

Comment: print(a,b) I'd suggest adding in your for for loop. So you can see 0 0 ,0 1,0 2, 0 3, which adds to 6. It adds a,b to result on each interation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first `a` loop iteration, `a` will be `0` so adding it will be irrelevant. The `b` loop for that iteration will go through the `b` values `0, 1, 2, 3`, which sum to `6` (the `print` is outside of the `b` loop).

The second `a` iteration will have `a` as `1`, so you will be adding `1+0, 1+1, 1+2, 1+3` or `10`. This is added to the `6` from the previous loop to give you `16`.

And so on, up until you exceed `stop`, whatever that value is.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help here. I am trying to wrap my head around nested loops.